# How to execute Insert query within VBA code

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to select rows from one table based on condition that it matches with user names from 2nd table.  I am getting error just running this query.
Next, I need to insert these selected rows into 3rd table.

Currently I am getting syntax error for strSQL1. Thanks!

```
Public Sub CalculateUA1_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim UsersTname As String
Dim SCCMTname As String
Dim UsersAppList1 As String


Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim strSQLWhere As String


Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

UsersTname = "UsersList"
SCCMTname = "SCCM1"
UsersAppList1 = "tbl_UsersApplicationList1"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(UsersTname)

strSQL1 = "SELECT s.User_Name0, s.[Machine name], s.displayName0, s.Mail0, 
s.AD_Site_Name0, s.[Application Name], s.[Application Version] FROM  '" & 
SCCMTname & "' as S  ; "

strSQLWhere = "user_name0 in  ( SELECT [SOE ID] FROM  '" & UsersTname & "' 
)"

strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " Where " & strSQLWhere

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL1
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO '" & UsersAppList1 & "'  VALUES ('" & strSQL1 & "' 
);"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL2
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Too many errors. You'd better create SQL in query builder, then copy it to code, replacing constants with variables. strSQL1 cannot be executed using RunSQL and you don't need it. Create and execute INSERT

Comment: I do have query within access working all good, I am trying to create access form for other users to use.  For that I need to write this query within VBA.  if not runsql then what command should I use like db.execute?

Comment: If the queries work in Access already, the main problem is generating proper SQL in VBA code.  Sergey just gave you the code (a disservice in my opinion), but the real key is learning to use breakpoints, inspecting (i.e. watching) variables, stepping through code, etc.... learning how to debug properly.  In particular, if you have a problem with a generated SQL statement, then you should inspect the final SQL text from the code so that you can verify the syntax.  One easy way to do this is like `Print.Debug strSQL1` to display the text in the VBA immediate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim UsersTname As String
Dim SCCMTname As String
Dim UsersAppList1 As String


Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim strSQLWhere As String


Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

UsersTname = "UsersList"
SCCMTname = "SCCM1"
UsersAppList1 = "tbl_UsersApplicationList1"

strSQL1 = "SELECT s.User_Name0, s.[Machine name], s.displayName0, s.Mail0, " & _
    "s.AD_Site_Name0, s.[Application Name], s.[Application Version] FROM  [" & SCCMTname & "]  as S; "

strSQLWhere = "user_name0 in  (SELECT [SOE ID] FROM  [" & UsersTname & "])"

strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " Where " & strSQLWhere

'variant 1: append to existing table, it should have columns with the same names as in SQL1
strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO [" & UsersAppList1 & "]  " & strSQL1

'variant 2: create new table. Existing table with the same name will be deleted
strSQL2 = "SELECT * INTO [" & UsersAppList1 & "]  FROM (" & strSQL1 & ");)"

db.Execute strSQL2, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thanks it is working for creating new table now.  However, for my solution I require to append into the existing table.  I tried to modify your code but couldn't get it working.  Currently I am trying this code strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO [" & UsersAppList1 & "] (User Name,Machine Name, Display Name, Email Address, Site Name, Application Name, Application Version)  (" & strSQL1 & ");"

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  When tried again your code does work.  Thank you very much! :-)